# Simple Terminal Command Question - Is there a command to pull a certain line out of an input?

Tags: command-line, terminal, grep

I have a simple question. Is there a command that allows you to pull a certain line out of an input? Like if I wanted the 7th line from ifconfig. Is there a way to do this: `ifconfig | [command] 7`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use sed to extract a particular line from a file and/or from standard in as follows

`sed -n '7p' filename` or

```
some_command | sed -n '7p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

`ifconfig | head -n 7 | tail -n 1`

Comment: Or, slightly more succinctly: `ifconfig | head -7 | tail -1`